# dlopen failed to load 32 bit instead of 64 bit library

Tags: android, dlopen, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have developed an application which uses 32 bit library `libmylibrary.so` but when I use `system.loadLibrary("mylibrary")`, it says that `cannot find library in /system/lib64 or /vendor/lib64`. I don't see my library in `/data/app-lib .. etc`. My Android version is `5.1.1`. I even copied my library in `/system/lib64` but it is still giving error message that `dlopen failed to load 32 bit instaed of 64 bit`. Please provide some valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> it says that cannot find library in `/system/lib64`

*IF* the application is looking for libraries in `lib64`, there is a high chance that the application is a 64-bit app. If so, it will *never* load 32-bit library, no matter how hard you try.

On Linux, you can check whether the app is 64-bit by starting it, and then doing `cat /proc/$pid/maps`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Employed Russian , I did a mistake . I added my native library in libs folder of my application.But didn't added it to build path dependencies and libraries in my android studio.After i added it to build path ,i am able to see my 32 bit library in /data/data/app-name/libs folder.Since i am using 
only one 32 bit library it got loaded and working fine.