# 32bit so file on a 64bit device

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a pre-built library on my phone but I get this error

```
 dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.test.myapplication/lib/arm64/libtest.so" 
 is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

How do I make it work on my 64bit device?

This is my code

```
MainActivity mthis = MainActivity.this;

Button load;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                System.loadLibrary("test");
                Toast.makeText(mthis, "Success load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                String error = e.getMessage();
                Log.e("Library",error);
                Toast.makeText(mthis, "No lib", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried putting this on my apps gradle but still won't work

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64_v8a", 
                "arm64", "x86", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64"
    }
```

My device is [Elephone P8000 v1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwip_s2Jt-bPAhWKro8KHYyuD1oQFgg7MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elephone.hk%2FP8000.html&usg=AFQjCNGvxpxrbBWtYecJpia5msE-nsDBXQ)

This question might've been answered already but their method does not work for me

**EDIT 2**  I haven't changed anything but for some unknown reason I get this error instead, the previous error is gone

```
dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.test.myapplication/lib/arm/libtest.so"
has unexpected e_machine: 3
```

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28919031/1050927

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reply Alex, but as you can see from my code, I'm already using `System.loadLibrary("test");`, and I don't have Android.mk

Comment: I mean to build the app in 32bit (Android.mk one), according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056720/dlopen-failed-to-load-32-bit-instead-of-64-bit-library), seems you build your app in 64bit, and system try to find library in 64bit

Comment: @Alex Again, thank you for your time, I have editted my question